# Environment variables have different values depending how CMD.exe is launched

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I have a command setup in the Registry as a folder association, so I can shift + right-click any folder and open a VS2010 prompt there, instead of having to open a command prompt and then CD to the directory I'm working in. But it's not working...

Setup:

`JAVA_HOME` is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04` in Computer > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables...

When I do the following the correct value is output:

Start > Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) (`%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86`):

Output (correct):

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium\VC>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04
```

But when I do the following the wrong (old) value is used:

Shift + right-click a folder, select "Open VS2010 prompt here" (`cmd /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat" x86 && cd /d "%V" && title Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)"` in the Registry):

Output **(wrong)**:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

E:\Hg>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27
```

Why are the values different??? Where is the second instance reading these values from?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `%comspec%` in the second entry as well?

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg: %comspec% doesn't get expanded when run from the Registry. I created a batch file that calls `%comspec%/k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat" x86 && cd /d "%V" && title Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)"` and called *that* from the Registry - gives same (wrong) behaviour as 2nd case above.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there are 2 sets of environment variables. One for the user and one for the entire system:

[image]

Make sure to have both adjusted. Sometimes the user variables are set, sometimes they aren't.

Comment: There is only 1 entry for JAVA_HOME and that's under "System variables".